# Manipulating a graph using a Bezier Curve

Tags: c#, math, bezier

I've looked around and nothing quite seems to be what I'm trying to do;
Which is, given an already drawn graph of points, use the mouse to create the 3rd control point necessary for a quadratic Bezier curve and then calculate the new position of all the points.

I'm mainly basing my work off of this equation from wikipedia;
[image: Quadratic Bezier Equation]

What I'm doing is as follows;

```
foreach (PointPair p in RelevantPoints)
{
    double t = (p.X - startPoint.X)/(endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
    p.Y = p.Y -
        Functions.CalculateBezierPoint(startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y, 
            referencePoint.Y, t);
}

public static double CalculateBezierPoint(double startY, double endY, 
    double referenceY, double t)
{
    return Math.Pow(1 - t, 2)*startY + 2*(1 - t)*t*referenceY + 
        Math.Pow(t, 2)*endY;
}
```

Where `referencePoint` is the current mouse position.
I'm not much of a mathematician and that's pretty clear as at present, the graph bends in a simple parabola instead of being biased towards the mouse position like you would expect from a Bezier curve.

I've only calculated Y values because, in this instance, X values cannot be moved.
`t` is also calculated every time because the X values are, 99% of the time, not of a uniform distance. That shouldn't affect things though unless I've misunderstood what the `t` value is meant to be.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood t. The value of t is from 0 to 1. As t varies from 0 to 1, B(t) describes a the curve from start point to end point. When t = 0, B(t) = P0, is the start point. When t = 1, B(t) = P2, is the end point. When 1 > t > 0, B(t) describes each point on Bezier curve. Therefore, in order to draw the curve, you should iterate t from 0 to 1, calculate each B(t), and draw each point on the canvas.

Pseudocode:

```
for (t from 0 to 1, different increment is 0.01) {
    point_x = B(t, P0_x, P1_x, P2_x);
    point_y = B(t, P0_y, P1_y, P2_y);
    point_z = B(t, P0_z, P1_z, P2_z);
    draw_point(point_x, point_y, point_z);
}

function B(t, P0, P1, P2) {
    return (1-t)*(1-t)*P0 + 2*t*(1-t)*P1 + t*t*P2;
}
```

Comment: The way I understood it, `t` is just the steps between points to be calculated. The way I'm calculating `t` will give me a value between 0 and 1, and should serve the same purpose as manually incrementing it, unless you can explain better why this wouldn't work?

Comment: To draw a new Bezier Curve, just use new P0, P1, P2 then you can get the new one. The old curve is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think you've read my question properly, the old curve is very relevant; the X values cannot move. Perhaps Bezier curve is not the solution to what I'm after, but neither is what you're saying.

Comment: I don't get it, why X values cannot be moved, if you what to redraw a Bezier curve, only using 3 control points is enough. If you what to find the relevant point with same x on the new curve, solve this equation x=B(t) and get t (0<=t<=1), then use this t to get y for the relevant point.

Comment: @FizzBuzz If you have x value and want to get y, you need to compute t first. Solving t is to solve x=(1-t)*(1-t)*P0+2*t*(1-t)*P1+t*t*P2, x, P0, P1, P2 is known, it is to solve quadratic equation with one unknown, not the way you did.